# How to get latest -1 table name

Tags: sas

I have a query that gives me latest table name in a library but now i also have sitation where i want the lastest-1 table name for eg

if latest date is
BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JUL2023_MAIN

if i do -1 i want

BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JUN2023_MAIN

Here is the code i have used for getting latest table

```
proc sql outobs=1;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'KALP51' and memname like 'BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_%_MAIN'
    order by input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.)
desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition where the date is < max date and it will always return the second-to-last value.

```
proc sql outobs=1;
    select memname, input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.) as date format=monyy7.
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'KALP51' and memname like 'BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_%_MAIN'
    having calculated date < max(calculated date)
    order by calculated date desc;
quit;
```

Comment: its working thanks a lot , just smal request i dont want the date coulmn i just want the memer name col , can you help here ?

Comment: Replace `calculated date` with `input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.)`. If you're creating a table, drop the column: `create table want(drop=date) as`

Comment: Hey thanks your answer worked quite welll for me , i have a question regarding this , if lets suppose i dont have any kind of date mentioned in te table name , i want to get the latest created tabe in the library , how can i do that instead of relying on the table name itself ? , i mean ofc i dont want all the tables , i will filter it with the like query first but the part where im trying to get the lastes from those is based on the date mentined , so is there any direct way to get the table name based on date created ?, also please cover the -1 scenario with this one also

Comment: Please create a separate question for this and it can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to also group tables by branch the following will work

Example:

The newest in group will have seq=1 and the first previous will have seq=2.

```
data 
  work.BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_MAY2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JUN2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_JUL2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_OUT_TOUCH_JAN2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_OUT_TOUCH_AUG2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_XYZ_FUBAR_JUL2023_MAIN
  work.BRANCH_XYZ_FUBAR_APR2023_SUB_A
  work.BRANCH_XYZ_FUBAR_JUL2023_SUB_A
;
  xyz = 1 ;
run;

data tables;
  set sashelp.vtable(keep=libname memname);
  where libname = 'WORK';

  do index = 1 to countw(memname,'_');
    namepart = scan(memname,index,'_');
    namedate = input(namepart,?? monyy7.); format namedate monyy7.;
    if missing(namedate) then continue;
    p = index(memname,trim(namepart));
    nameprefix = substr(memname,1,p-2);
    namesuffix = substr(memname,p+8);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=tables;
  by nameprefix namesuffix descending namedate ;
run;

data want(keep=libname memname namedate seq);
  set tables;
  by nameprefix namesuffix;
  if first.namesuffix then seq=1; else seq+1;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will save it for later , when a similar situation will occur

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented function MONOTONIC() which may be helpful

```
data aaa bbb ccc ;
run ;

proc sql ;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'WORK' 
    having monotonic()=2
    order by memname desc
    ;
quit ;
```

See: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/MONOTONIC-function-in-PROC-SQL/ta-p/475752

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stu Sztukowski i got the solution but i didnt wanted the extra column that i was getting in the initial by @Stu Sztukowski

so i modeified the code according to my need , here is the modified code

```
proc sql outobs=1;
    select memname
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = 'KALP51' and memname like 'BRANCH_AQB_INDIA_%_MAIN'
    having input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.) < input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.)
    order by input(scan(memname, -2, '_'), monyy7.)desc;
quit;
```